# How to create custom emoji through telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Environment introduction:
PHP: 8.0
Laravel: 9
irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk : 3.13

Below is my test code

```
$path = storage_path('sticker/sticker (1).png');

$result = Telegram::createNewStickerSet(
     [
         'user_id' => 123456,
         'name' => 'test_sticker_set_by_xxxxxx_bot',
         'title' => 'test',
         'stickers' => [
             ['sticker' => 'CAACAgUAAxkBAAIfe2VDjNifjeWLl4ha4IJCxa9C8U3XAAKaBQACeYsgVw7fwwdsGB4JMwQ','emoji_list'=>[''],'keywords'=>[0,2]]
         ],
         'sticker_format' => 'animated',
         'png_sticker'=>InputFile::create($path),
         'emojis' =>'',
         'sticker_type' => 'custom_emoji',
         'width' => 512,
         'height' => 512,
     ]
);
```

Creating custom emoji appears: "Bad Request: STICKER_PNG_DIMENSIONS" and "Invalid resource type: array"

How to create custom emoji via telegram bot